# textbox browser autocompletion options do not fire keypress/keyup

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, bind, keypress

I have an `<input type = "text">` binded with a "keypress" event, as follows (see jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/RMyc7/):

```
<form name = "myform" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "mytext" id = "text_id"/>
    <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text_id').bind('keyup', function() {
        console.log('pressed!');
    });
});
</script>​
```

My problem is that if I select one of the browser recommendations for the field (previously entered values), then the keyup event won't fire. What do you suggest I should do to work around this?

Tested on chromium 17 and Firefox 10

Thanks as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting 'autocomplete=off' to my field to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to both `keyup` and `change`.

```
$('#text_id').on('keyup change', function () {
    // Code that works well for both cases, since they are
    // a bit different.
})
```

Comment: onchange doesn't seem to fire either

Comment: It does fire, but only when focus is moved away from the field. If you MUST catch the change early, maybe polling every 100ms could trick it, but that's ugly.

Comment: yes, that's what I must do and yes, that would be ugly. Thanks anyway though